Autocomplete breaks in inner type with literal types vallue
I need a type to hold the various options my type needs:

Options which holds the possible values as a union and a default value.
PickOptions that allows a type to use only the options needed and can specify, if needed, a different default value.

export type Options = {
    way: ['<-' | '->',  '->'].         // [all, default]
    depth: ['flat' | 'deep', 'deep']   // [all, default]
}

export type PickOptions<
    K extends keyof Options,
    D extends {[L in K]?: Options[L][0]} = {}
> = {[L in K]: L extends keyof D ? D[L] : Options[L][1]}

type _test = PickOptions<'way' | 'depth', {way: ''}> // no autocomplete here

The issue I have is when picking the default value. Whilst the key can handle autocomplete, the new default can't and I do not understand why.
For example, the type can be used if we need the way option and define it to be backwards.
type ATypeThatNeedWay<X, O extends PickOptions<'way', {way '<-'}> = ....

Playground link

TS doesn't support autocomplete on literal types in generics very well, see ms/TS#52898. It's not something TS can do as-is. Are you looking for a github issue like the one above to ask for it to be changed? Or are you looking for some kind of workaround?

Thank you for postinf that issue, and if they re is a workaround gor my special use cas yes i'll gladly take it

The only workaround I can imagine is to avoid literals in property types, and use them as key types instead, possibly as shown in this playground link. Whether or not that meets your needs, does it fully address the question (along with the github issue above)? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what's missing?

When i do try your playground i do not see autocomplete works am i missing something?

https://imgur.com/LhnWC5X ‍♂️

@jcalz should i wrtie an update in the question referencing the typescript issue, or should i wait for you to answer so by validating you're answer the question can be validated so people can find the answer if they come across here ?

TypeScript doesn't currently have great support for auto-suggestion and/or auto-completion of literal types. It seems to do a fairly good job if such types are the keys of an object type, but not when they are values.  There's an open issue at microsoft/TypeScript#52898 about this general problem, and it's classified as a bug in the Backlog and labeled as Help Wanted, so if you're interested in seeing this improved, you might want to consider trying to fixing it yourself, as the TypeScript team will consider merging pull requests submitted by the community.  Until and unless it gets addressed though, there's not much you can do other than give up or work around it.
One possible workaround is to move your literals into key position so that you at least get auto-suggestion:
export type PickOptions<
    K extends keyof Options,
    D extends { [L in K]?: Partial<Record<string & Options[L][0], any>> } = {}
> = { [L in K]: L extends keyof D ? keyof D[L] : Options[L][1] }

type _test = PickOptions<'way' | 'depth',
    { way: { │ } }>; // <-- auto-suggest at cursor yields:
//           ^ ☐ "->"   (property) "->"?: any
//           ^ ☐ "<-"   (property) "<-"?: any

And if you accept the autosuggestion you need to give a dummy value you don't care about:
type _test = PickOptions<'way' | 'depth',
    { way: { "->": 0 } }>;

It's not wonderful, but you can at least get IntelliSense to suggest things instead of just reporting an error when you get it wrong.
Playground link to code
